# É possível compartilhar falhas de validação entre controllers aninhados?

Tags: php, laravel-4

Tenho dois modelos, um filho do outro, `User` e `Address` onde `User>hasOne>Address` e estou pra fazer o seguinte:

**Request**:

```
[
  'User' => [ 
    'name' => 'fulano', 
    'etc' => 'etc' 
  ],

  'Address' => [ 
    'street' => 'rua x', 
    'etc' => 'etc' 
  ]
]
```

**UserController**:

- Valida os dados em `['User']`
- Dá create no User
- Chama o `AddressController` e repassando os dados de `['Address']`

**AddressController**:

- Valida os dados em `['Address']`
- Dá create no `Address`

Mas não estou achando uma forma para caso a validação falhe em ambos os *controllers* eu consiga devolver para o usuário todas os campos que falharam.

Já fiz uma vez com `try-catch`, mas o problema é que se a validação falha em `UserController` ele encerra aí e não chega a validar o endereço, não mostrando se tiver algo errado, fazendo com que o usuário tenha que talvez corrigir o que escreveu duas vezes, uma pra corrigir os dados dele e outra depois para corrigir o endereço porque o sistema não informou que o endereço também estava errado.

Então o que me passa:

- Existe alguma forma de eu não precisar usar o `try-catch` e conseguir pegar todas as falhas de endereço e passar para algum lugar pra tratar?
  (ouvi falar algo sobre `dispatcher` ou algo do tipo, mas não sei se é algo pra ser usado aqui)

Eu poderia validar tudo no `UserController`, mas ficaria uma tripa e caso precisasse fazer um `update` no Endereço precisaria ter novamente a validação de endereço no `AddressControler`;

Como sair dessa?

**Edit:**
Um exemplo de como estava fazendo (não consegui achar o original)

```
// User Controller
public function store($data){
    try {
        $this->validate($data['user']);
        $user = User::create($data);

        // Chama o Store de Address e passa os valores
        $address = (new AddressController())->store($user, $data);

        return $user;
    } catch(ValidationFailException $e) { 
        // Aqui captura a primeira validação que falhar
        Session::flash('fails', $ex->getFails());
        return Redirect::back();
    }
}

// Address Controller
public function store($data){
    try {
        $this->validate($data['address']);
        $address = new Address($data);
        $address->user()->associate($user);
        $address->save();

        return $address;
}

// Ambos os controladores tem um método validador nesse formato
public function validate($data)  {
    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'campo' => 'required',
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){
        throw new ValidationFailException('As seguinter validações falharam', $validator->messages()->toArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: Bom eu faria tudo em no mesmo controller e no form utilizaria os campos respectivos validaria todos e depois gravaria separado. Não sei qual é a dificuldade, mas eu acho desnecessário o controller pra enderço. A sua implementação pode postar na pergunta?

Comment: Foi só um exemplo simples, preciso do controller porque terei que editar em partes separadas, pegar alguns padrões com lat/long e umas paradas com fotos, separei mais pra não ficar um arquivo gigante. Pior que não tenho implementação, tenho só uma antiga como disse acima (esse foi desnecessário) com o try-catch, coloco assim que achar...